# NodeJS: Input values not reset to their given values

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here I have the NodeJS code for form validation that I was working on. I cannot get it reset the value put by the user.

The validation doesn't do anything much, I just wanted to reset the values of the input form with the values provided by the user. 
Someone please help me.

Here's the code:

**signup Route:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var vm = {
    title: 'Join us now,  Brovis'
    };
  res.render('signup', vm);
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var flagChecker= true;
  if (flagChecker) {
    var vm = {
      title: 'Create an account',
      input: req.body,
      error: 'Something went wrong, Brovis'
    };
    delete vm.input.password;
    return res.render('signup', vm);
  }
  res.redirect('/');
});
module.exports = router;
```

**signup's index.hbs:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/silog.css">
 <div class="jumbotron">
                 <div class="container">
                 <div class = "row">
                 <div class = "col-md-6 theForm">
                        <div class="form-box">
                            <div class="form-top">
                                    <h2>Sign up now</h2>
                                    <p>Join the community now:</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="registration-form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="firstname">First name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="form-first-name" placeholder="First name" class="form-first-name form-control" id="form-first-name" required value = "{{input.firstname}}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="password">Last name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Last name..." class="form-last-name form-control" id="form-last-name" required value = {{input.password}}>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign me up!</button>
                                </form>
                          </div>
                        <span style = "color:red; font-weight: 600">{{error}}</span>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Your input name/id is `form-first-name`, but because you've used `firstname` instead of `form-first-name`; the value provided by the user is not being reset. Replace it with:

```
<input type="text" name="form-first-name" placeholder="First name" class="form-first-name form-control" id="form-first-name" required value = "{{input.form-first-name}}">
```

Also, you've missed the quotes in the second input field. it should be:

```
<input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Last name..." class="form-last-name form-control" id="form-last-name" required value = "{{input.form-last-name}}">
```

This will work.

Cheers.